Problem with the reactivity issue in svelte
I am writing this code in svelte where I have developed a component to re use in my code. However, I am giving a reactive input to that component. At first it is okay but when the iobStringLatest is updated with the new value, the AnnotatedText component is not rendering automatically.
<script>
    import AnnotatedText from './AnnotatedText.svelte';
        
    let currentIndex = 0;
    let iobString = ['first string', 'second string', 'third string'];
    // Reactive declaration to automatically update iobStringLatest when currentIndex changes
    $: iobStringLatest = iobString[currentIndex];

    function goToPreviousDocument() {
        if (currentIndex > 0) {
            currentIndex -= 1;
                        console.log('currentIndex, ', currentIndex)
                    iobStringLatest = iobString[currentIndex];
                    iobStringLatest = iobStringLatest;
                    console.log('Previous ', iobStringLatest)                   
        }
    }

    function goToNextDocument() {
        if (currentIndex < iobString.length - 1) {
            currentIndex += 1;
                    console.log('currentIndex, ', currentIndex)
                    iobStringLatest = iobString[currentIndex];
                    iobStringLatest = iobStringLatest;
                    console.log('Next, ', iobStringLatest)
        }
    }
</script>

<div>
    <button on:click={goToPreviousDocument}>Previous</button>
    <button on:click={goToNextDocument}>Next</button>
    <AnnotatedText {iobStringLatest} />
</div>

I am trying this one.

I am using svelte

Can you post the contents of the AnnotatedText component?`

Your code seems to work. Here's a repl
https://svelte.dev/repl/d88a621bd709466c86597e290abd76e6?version=4.2.16
